# Create blank XML File and then Append to it

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am writing a windows forms program in C# and I want to be able to save information to an XML file.
When I first create the XML file, I just want to be able to ad the declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

and then the root node which I want called "Contacts".

The final file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Contacts>
    <Contact>
        <Name>name</Name>
        <Address>address</Address>
    <Contact>
<Contacts>
```

There will be multiple `<Contact></Contact>` elements.

The problem I am having is when I first create the XML file.

My XML operations are in their own class.
This is the method to create the file:

```
public void createFile()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            //Populate with data here if necessary, then save to make sure it exists
            xmlFile = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XComment("XML File for storing " + RootName));
            xmlFile.Save(FileName);
        }
    }
```

When I try to run this, I get an ArgumentNullException was unhandled error.

Any ideas how to actually get the data in the file and have it save?
Thanks

Comment: have you considered debugging? Or looking at the stacktrace to see which argument of what is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a root element in the file:

```
xmlFile.Add( new XElement( "Contacts" ) );
```

Although the error you are getting suggests something else is going on. Perhaps `Filename` is null?

Comment: I added that in there right after the new XDocument statement, and I still get the error. The file never gets created. It seems like I have to populate the file with something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: The xmlFile.Save(FileName) is throwing the error. I found out the problem, I was never setting the FileName, which is a public accessor for a private backing field.

Comment: Hehe as I guessed then.